# INTEGRITY violation - attempt to store into protected memory

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, rtos, integrity

I am using

```
GetClockAlarm(Clock TheClock, Boolean *Repeat, Time *AlarmTime, Time *AlarmInterval)
```

for fetching the clock time and interval into out parameters of API.

`AlarmTime` is pointer to structure which has (seconds and fraction as a structure member).

I am getting an error "attempt to store into protected memory".

I have tried using pointers referring structure but it is not useful.

```
void GetClockAlarm_(Clock TheClock){
    Time T3, AI;
    GetClockAlarm(Vclk2, true, &T3, &AI);
    printf("T3.Seconds = %llu\t\t T3.Fraction=%d\t\t \n",T3.Seconds,T3.Fraction);
}
```

Comment: `GetClockAlarm(Vclk2, true, &T3, &AI);` : your compiler should have warned you, see answer below. Compile with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> GetClockAlarm(Clock TheClock, Boolean *Repeat,Time *AlarmTime, Time *AlarmInterval)
> ```

Look at the second argument which takes `Boolean *` but you are passing `Boolean`.

Maybe you want as below.

```
Time T3, AI;
Boolean boolVar = true;
GetClockAlarm(Vclk2, &boolVar, &T3, &AI);
```